# order confirmation email is not sent for guest's order only Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, order-email

In the backend shows (The order confirmation email is not sent), if i clicked on send email it sends the message.

and if the customer logged in working fine.

Configuration

**Sales -> Sales Emails -> General Settings -> Asynchronous sending is Disable**

Comment: Could you clarify: 
1. When you go into the order, in the Sales-area, and select 1) an order for a guest and 2) an order for a registered customer what is written to the right of the order number? It should say (The order confirmation email was sent). 
2. How do you know that the email isn't sent to guests and sent to logged in customers?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When the customer placed order as guest " confirmation email is not sent " and if registered customer shows "The order confirmation email was sent" and i'm using megaplaza as smtp.

Comment: Any updates? I'm facing the same...

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar Unfortunately, I can't find a solution yet :(

Comment: Maybe upgrade to 2.2.1

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar Did you tried it?